# Vary line with Z-axis for imported SVG file

Tags: openscad, blender, meshmixer, tinkercad

I have an SVG file of a line drawing.  When I import it into Tinkercad it generates a 3D version with the width of the lines remaining constant along the Z-axis (as expected).  I would like to generate a similar STL but with the line width narrowing for increasing values of Z.  (Similar to the Bevel option in some of the Tinkercad Text shapes).

Can anyone point me at a tutorial on how to do this in Tinkercad, Blender, Meshmixer or Open SCAD?

Comment: I think this might depend on exactly what shape/file you're dealing with and how much of a bevel you're wanting to add. It might be worth adding screenshot(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenSCAD you could create a bevel using the minkowski transformation by transforming the curve using tapered shape such as a pyramid or as I do below a tapered cylinder:

```
minkowski() {

  linear_extrude(1)
    import("drawing.svg");
  
  cylinder(h = 20, r1 = 10, r2 = 1); 
}
```

[image: Example result in OpenSCAD]